# Get JSON response after a Stripe charge is made

Tags: javascript, php, json, stripe-payments, fetch-api

I am building a simple checkout with Stripe elements. After a successful charge is made, I would like to retrieve the `JSON`response from Stripe. From my understanding, a charge object should be created after each made charge.

Simple example - after a charge is made, how to display thank you message on the checkout form itself? My reasoning was that after pulling the `JSON` I could check if the charge is successful and act accordingly.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the response I get now is something I can't decipher in the console.

`Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost/iq-test/charge.php", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost/iq-test/charge.php", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}`

Expanding this in the console didn't help me either. I am a designer who knows some code, but far from this level.

Here are relevant portions of both `JS` and `PHP`files.

`charge.js`

```
// Handle form submission.
  const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  const errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors')
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // here we lock the form
    form.classList.add('processing'); 
    stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // here we unlock the form again if there's an error
      form.classList.remove('processing');
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
      }
    });
  });

    // Submit the form with the token ID.
     function stripeTokenHandler(token) {


// Let's add name, email and phone to be sent alongside token
     const recipient_name = form.querySelector('input[name=recipient- 
     name]').value;
     const recipient_email = form.querySelector('input[name=recipient- 
     email]').value;
     const recipient_phone = form.querySelector('input[name=recipient- 
     phone]').value;

     let formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('stripeToken', token.id);
     formData.append('recipient_email', recipient_email); 
     formData.append('recipient_name', recipient_name); 
     formData.append('recipient_phone', recipient_phone); 

     // grab the form action url
     const backendUrl = form.getAttribute('action');
     // Post the info via fetch
     fetch(backendUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "same-origin",
      credentials: "same-origin",
      body: formData
     })
     .then(response => response)
     .then(response => console.log(response))

     }
```

`charge.php`

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";


\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('xxx');

 $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
 $amount = 299;

 //item meta
 $item_name = 'IQ Test Score Results';
 $item_price = $amount;
 $currency = "usd";
 $order_id = uniqid();


 try
  {
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
'source'  => $token,
'amount'  => $amount,
'currency' => $currency,
'description' => $item_name,
'metadata' => array(
  'order_id' => $order_id
 )
  ));
 }
catch(Exception $e)
{
$error = $e->getMessage();
show__errorPayment($error);

}

if($charge->status == 'succeeded') {
echo "Charge Created";
$charge_json = $charge->__toJSON();
}

?>
```

Comment: Charging is a two step process, first one completes when user fills in his details in the strip form and hits enter if all goes well a token is generated and sent (alongwith other details) via ajax to server (charge.php) for the 2nd part.If this too succeeds you get a json response with `status='succeeded'` so you just need to check whether it's available and equal to `succeeded`.Also I don't see in the code for returning json in charge.php please post full code.

Comment: Thanks for making things clearer now. That last part you wrote is a-ha moment for me. I assumed that it happens automatically, Could you please just point me in the right direction, e.g. What to parse/convert to json and how to output that back?

Comment: Sry about the late reply, `then(response => console.log(response)) }` this part is what dumping the response to your browser console.If you are familiar with js, individual keys can be accesses like `respose.status` so just need an if statement for checking status ==200 (or ok== true) and show your message via an alert() or some custom <div>.

Comment: After you opened my eyes on how JSON response actually works, I managed to solve the issue. Thanks once again, you put me on the right path :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it after helpful comment from @viney. For some reason I thought that `JSON` response will happen automatically and no action is needed on my part.

Here is the code I added to `charge.php`, now it echoes back the `JSON` response.

```
// Response
$success = true;
$err = '';
$recipient_name = $_POST['recipient_name'];
$recipient_email = $_POST['recipient_email'];

try
{
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'source'  => $token,
    'amount'  => $amount,
    'currency' => $currency,
    'description' => $item_name,
    'metadata' => array(
      'order_id' => $order_id
  )
  ));
}
catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  $success = false;
  $err = "Declined - $e";
}

echo json_encode(array('success' => $success, 'err' => $err, 'recipient_name' => $recipient_name, 'recipient_email' => $recipient_email));
```

For `charge.js` I parsed the response to `JSON`, because the response is a `ReadableStream` object.

```
       fetch(backendUrl, {
          method: "POST",
          mode: "same-origin",
          credentials: "same-origin",
          body: formData
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonData) {
         let data = jsonData;
         if(data.success == true){
          form.querySelector('.title').textContent = `
          Thank you ${data.recipient_name}, your payment was successful and we have 
         sent an email receipt to ${data.recipient_email}. `
         }
         else{
        errorElement.textContent = `There was an error with payment, please try again 
        or contact us at help@web.com`
       console.log(data.err)
       }
        });
```